# Update with Select on QueryDSL is possible? How?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, querydsl

I need to run an update statement similar to the one below on MySQL. It updates values in a table based on conditions of rows in the same table. Is there a way to achieve that in QueryDSL JPA (or even that native one)?

```
UPDATE items,
       (SELECT id, retail / wholesale AS markup, quantity FROM items)
       AS discounted
    SET items.retail = items.retail * 0.9
    WHERE discounted.markup >= 1.3
    AND discounted.quantity < 100
    AND items.id = discounted.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using derived table:

```
UPDATE items
SET items.retail = items.retail * 0.9
WHERE
items.id in (SELECT id FROM (select * from items) discounted WHERE discounted.quantity < 100);
```

I've removed few parts from your query but you get gist of the solution.

Comment: The query that I posted is already working, I asked how to do that through QueryDSL JPA or SQL library.